# Delete all character from filename before the last underscore _

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ho to delete all characters up to and including the last underscore `_` before the `.ext` from all filenames recursive in the CWD?

Is this best done by split and replace or regex (`^[^_]+_` ?)? The code below does not work (no erros msg.)

```
aaa_bbb_000_xxx.txt   ---> xxx.txt
__abc123_zzzz.txt     ---> zzzz.txt
111222.txt            ---> 111222.txt
```

Code:

```
import os

cwd = os.getcwd()

paths = (os.path.join(cwd, filename)
        for cwd, _, filenames in os.walk(cwd)
        for filename in filenames)

for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace("^[^_]+_")
    if newname != path:
        os.rename(path, newname)
```

Comment: `path.replace(^[^_]+_)` ? what???? this isn't valid, and replace doesn't support regexes.

Comment: thank you, any suggestion what would be the best way?

Comment: `'aaa_bbb_000_xxx.txt'.split('_')[-1]`

Comment: note that you shouldn't edit your question to reflect suggestions done by answers, because it makes answers completely off. I reverted to an earlier version and just fixed the missing quote typo. Now I have to update my answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is wrong:

```
for path in paths:
    newname = path.replace("^[^_]+_")
```

`str.replace` doesn't support regular expressions (and needs another argument: empty string), and (the main issue), your regular expression cannot work because `path` is the *full path with directory* so `^` doesn't work.

Also, your regex doesn't do the job. You just want to remove all chars until underscore (greedy mode) so that works:

```
re.sub(".*_","",s)
```

I would take the basename to apply replacement, then join it back to full path. Also note that if the target filename exists, `os.rename` will fail. I've added a protection against that.

The code below decomposes my approach:

```
import re
for path in paths:
    the_dir = os.path.dirname(path)
    newname = re.sub(".*_","",os.path.basename(path))
    newpath = os.path.join(the_dir,newname)
    if path != newpath:
        if os.path.exists(newpath):
           print("Warning: cannot rename into {}".format(newpath))
        else:
           os.rename(path,newpath)
```

Comment: Thank you. I use the code with `path = os.getcwd()`, but I am getting error: `NameError: name 'paths' is not defined.

Comment: I had a very similar solution but you beat me to it. +1

Comment: @HakariDo you still need your gencomp: `paths = (os.path.join(cwd, filename)
        for cwd, _, filenames in os.walk(cwd)
        for filename in filenames)`

Comment: I am running as updated in OP and getting: nameerror name 're'is not defined.

Comment: `import re` added.

Comment: `os.rename(path,newpath) FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: `

Comment: check my last edit. If the target file exists then it doesn't work

Comment: This works, thank you. But there are some python-renamed or generated files that seems to be "resistant" to this code (i.e., they are not truncated), while all other "regular and old" files are properly truncated. I suspect the problem maybe (?) with the file permissions. Any hints in this respect? Maybe including a line that updates file permissions in the cwd so this character deletion can take place.?

Comment: it's just that if the target file exists `rename` fails. try to delete the original file with `os.remove`. Probably not a permissions problem.

Comment: i think the regex is doing something different: (1) it does not work if the filename starts with an `_`, and (2) if the filename does not starts with an `_`, then it trims from the 1st character to before, not inclusive, the **first** underscore, not the last before the extension. Try on `_aaa_bbb__ccc_111.txt`

Comment: I didn't focus on the regex, but it's also _wrong_. Check my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think split would be the easiest way, though I'm not sure why you need replace.

Since you start out with path.join, why not "correct" the filename first and then join the paths? Right now it looks like you're making "wrong" filepaths, then go back and modify them.

```
filename = filename.split('_')[-1]
```

This splits the filename into a list of strings (along each "_") and returns the last entry, e.g. 'xxx.txt' for the first example above.

Comment: How would you do the actual rename with `filename = filename.split('_')[-1]`

Comment: You could try:
      newname = os.path.basename(path).split('_')[-1] (in place of your current newname line)